# How to give root privileges to a Twisted daemon

Tags: python, twisted, root, daemon

I have implemented a **client server application** using `Twisted` in python.

I realized that when I run a client as a daemon using `twistd`, even when running as root, it does not have **root privileges** any more.

Could you please tell me how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to run your daemon with the root privileges. This article may help you: http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/2011/10/04/running-twisted-daemons-with-twistd/

Comment: Yes, I have already read that! I know but the requirements of my task need me to do so.